# Excel #Value! error - but correct formula

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an Excel 2010 workbook with this formula:

```
=EOMONTH("01"&TEXT(B7,"MMM")&IF(MONTH(CMVAR)<4,TEXT(YEAR(CMVAR)-1,"YYYY"),TEXT(YEAR(CMVAR),"YYYY")),0)
```

It resolves when you are in the cell and press Enter, however when the workbook first opens or is refreshed, the result is `#VALUE!`. Here are the components:

**B7** `=IF(OR(MONTH(CMVAR)>6,MONTH(CMVAR)<4),"Apr",IF(MONTH(CMVAR)=4,TEXT(EDATE(CMVAR,-3),"MMM"),IF(MONTH(CMVAR)=5,TEXT(EDATE(CMVAR,-3),"MMM"),TEXT(EDATE(CMVAR,-3),"MMM"))))`

which equates to `Apr`.

**CMVAR** `31/03/2015`

The formula is being used because in April, May, June (first three fiscal periods) we require comparison data to show in the 12-period grid from the previous financial year. From July onwards we will have comparable data from the current year and so the grid can start from April. Once the month has been determined I'm trying to work out what the date of the end of that period is, taking into account that Jan, Feb and Mar are actually periods 10, 11 and 12 of the fiscal year and so the year element of the formula will be the prior year if CMVAR shows the date to be in any of those months.

Is there a better way that avoids the error or a way to fix it?

Comment: Do you need `B7` to be in text format?

Comment: Yes there is something strange going on when you use the TEXT function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not completely clear what result do you expect for different values of `CMVAR`, but looking at your formula, I suppose you want it to be:

[image]

You can calculate `Result` with the following formula:

```
=EOMONTH(CMVAR,-MAX(MOD(MONTH(CMVAR)-4,12),3))
```

If the picture above does not show your expected output, can you please prepare similar table?

**EDIT:**

To explain how the problem is solved, I have created additional columns with intermediate calculations:

[image]

- column `C` is the month difference between `CMVAR` and expected result - the goal is to find a formula returning this number
- column `D` calculates month of CMVAR
- column `E` - function `MOD` returns the remainder after number is divided by divisor (`12`).
- column `E` matches all values of `C`, except `0`,`1`,`2`, so in column `F` function `MAX` replaces those values with `3`

Comment: Thanks both. I don't have access to try until Monday but ill give your suggestions a try and let you know how I get on.  Regards.

Comment: This solution does do exactly what I'm after and so I'll accept it as the answer, but if I'm honest I'm not entirely sure what it is doing! It looks like it takes the value of a month and subtracts 4, then divides the result by 12 and multiplies by -1. Then offsets the current date by the result - is that correct?

Comment: @user2916488 I have edited my answer to add step by step explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your EOMONTH formula is going wrong because the TEXT part should be in the form TEXT(date,"YYYY"). YEAR(CMVAR) gives a number rather than a date.

You could use instead

```
=EOMONTH("01"&TEXT(B7,"MMM")&IF(MONTH(CMVAR)<4,TEXT(EDATE(CMVAR,-12),"YYYY"),TEXT(CMVAR"YYYY")),0)
```

or this may be easier than using the TEXT functions

```
=EOMONTH("01"&B7&IF(MONTH(CMVAR)<4,YEAR(CMVAR)-1,YEAR(CMVAR)),0)
```

Your B7 formula is OK but could be simplified to

```
=IF(OR(MONTH(CMVAR)>6,MONTH(CMVAR)<4),"Apr",TEXT(EDATE(CMVAR,-3),"MMM"))
```

Comment: Hi Tom, I tried your solution above and unfortunately it still gave the #value! error after I had ammended it. I have taken onboard your suggestion for B7 though - much easier to read than my original one! Thanks for your help :)